# What is the first Service to the Empire reward?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What, exactly, is the first reward, earned at 100 Imperial Service Medals, for the current Service to the Empire event? Is it supposed to be a completely new (previously unavailable) costume or just "extra inventory" of one or more of the existing costumes?

Answer (score 2):

Sad to say, it was just a regular costume for me (rebel pilot) and just adds one more to my inventory.

No new and "limited edition" costume at 100 medals, which is disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait and see what you get at 975 and 1200 medals. This is literally impossible. I've been playing nearly non stop all week and I'm only halfway through the 1200 medal prize with only a day left.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question about the reward at 100 medals?